# Extract specified columns while eliminating duplicate values

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, I'm trying to create a script for a CSV that removes columns that are not specified. In this instance, none of my columns have headers but I know that I want to only keep data from columns 30(AD), 31(AE), and 39(AM). I also would like to remove rows that have duplicate values when the columns are combined. How can I do this?

Comment: `import-csv -Header (1..39) -Path 'Path\To\CSV' | select 30, 31, 39 -Unique`

Comment: @PetSerAl Using `import-csv -Header (1..39) -Path 'J:\consult evv\splitfile_2.csv' | select 30, 31, 39 -Unique` gives me errors: `select : Cannot convert System.Int32 to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At line:1 char:123
+ ... ster\UBT_AllExceptChecks\splitfile_2.csv' | select 30, 31, 39 -Unique
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by using:

```
import-csv -Header (1..39) -Path 'Path\To\CSV' | select '30', '31', '39' -Unique
```